# Apache's Velocity -- getTemplate() call that takes a string not a filename?

Tags: apache, velocity

Wanting to do some fancy stuff... :P
We'd like to be able to pass a string that IS the file, instead of a string that simple a filename.

We're going to create a file in memory using a string/stringbuffer and we want the velocity engine to act upon that instead of reading in a file.

Does this function exist?

Many thanks!

Comment: could you elaborate how you are creating a file in memory (without using stringbuffer/stringbuilder?)

Comment: Durrr. Meant to put using a instead of instead of xD Sorry! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We added a StringResourceLoader in 1.5 and made it better in 1.6.  No need to implement your own.

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.6.4/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/StringResourceLoader.html